# How can I install zipruby under windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, zip, installation

I've been trying to get zipruby installed on my windoz box, but there has been little joy.
I'm confronted with this message.

```
Installing zipruby (0.3.6) with native extensions C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/li
b/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `rescue in block in build_ex
tensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::Extensi
onBuildError)
```

I would normally google things, and have in this case, but I see no answer. There seems to be nothing really on the topic of native extensions with respect to ruby. Not at least that I've found, though I'd love to be wrong.

Has anyone installed this gem on a windows box?
If you encountered the issue, how did you get past it/fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*<-- I am editing this answer as I work through.. if I eventually crack it, I'll have a log anyone can find... including me -->*

---

Steps I tried that (as yet) didn't work

1. download zlib-1.2.3-src.exe and run the install.
2. After the install (where I changed nothing) run the gem install.

   w:\ruby> gem install zipruby -- --with-opt-dir="C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\src\zlib\1.2.3\zlib-1.2.3"

The above didn't work, and I seem no closer

---

Steps that seem to leading somewhere.. **But ultimately let me down**

1. Installed two files. http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75848/rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p125.exe and https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe  I'm still working my way through the install, but I'll keep this answer fluid.

Where I'm at now.. Just where I started.

Answer (score 0):

There are [gem files for Windows available for download from RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=6124), they work with my Ruby 1.9.2 installation on Windows 7

```
gem install path.to\downloaded.gemfile
```